# SQL: Sub-intervals which are inside a month

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table `hirefire`. Below there is its simplified structure:

- `hired`   date
- `fired`   date
- `firereason` smallint

I spent a few hours writing queries for this table to solve a problem, my problem (simplified) is presented below:

This table describes when an employee starts work and when he goes to a vacation.

Intervals `hired..fired` from a row of this table (with `hired` included and `fired` not included into the interval) are called "hire intervals". I warrant that hire intervals don't override with each other and that `fired>=hired` for every row.

I call "fire intervals" all intervals `fired1..hired2` where `fired1` is the field `fired` from a row `r1` in this table and `hired2` is the field `hired` from the next row `r2` of this table where rows are sorted by the field `hired`. For each such interval it is assigned a "fire reason" (a ref to a primary ID of the table containing reason to leave the job, such as a vacation, parental leave, death, etc.) equal to the field `firereason` from `r1`.

Let there is given a month (by an SQL DATE variable which contains the first day of the month).

I need the set of non-empty intersections of fire intervals with the given month. (That is I need info about these intervals which have at least one day in common with the given month.)

MySQL+PHP

Comment: "fired date" = "when he goes to a vacation" :D

Comment: You description is probably missing some kind of identifier to know *who* is hired/fired ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: Yes, it misses employee ID. I've leaved it out for simplicity

Comment: I've decided to give up the attempt to solve this in SQL. I will read **all** data from the DB (for a given employee) and process it in PHP, without further SQL queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have to find all the [fired,hired] intervals.

My approach here is to first select all the "fired date" in the given range (synthesizing *fake* fired date at the start and end of the required interval). Then doing the same for hire date -- and finally matching them by pair.

As a picture worth 1000 words here is graphically how the query works:
[image: A query to find values not in range]

That leads to a rather complex query (and mostly inefficient -- probably requiring several temp table + filesort):

```
SELECT * FROM
( -- Keep numbered list of "fired" date
SELECT (@i := @i+1) as n, F.* FROM (
  SELECT @start AS fired 
  UNION SELECT fired FROM hirefire
    WHERE fired > @start and hired < @end
  UNION SELECT @end
  ) AS F
   JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) AS init -- initialize @i
   ORDER BY F.fired ASC
) AS F
JOIN
( -- Keep numbered list of "hired" date
SELECT (@j := @j+1) as n, H.* FROM (
  SELECT @start AS hired 
  UNION SELECT hired FROM hirefire
    WHERE fired > @start and hired < @end
  UNION SELECT @end
  ) AS H
   JOIN (SELECT @j := 0) AS init -- initialize @j
   ORDER BY H.hired ASC
) AS H
ON( F.n+1 = H.n )
WHERE H.hired <> F.fired;
```

For a live example, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a841d0/39

As an example:

```
create table hirefire(pk serial, hired int, fired int);
insert into hirefire(hired, fired) values
 (1,3), (5,10), (12,14), (16,25);
SET @start = 4;
SET @end = 30;
```

will produce

```
+----+--------+-------+
| N  | FIRED  | HIRED |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  |     4  |     5 |
| 2  |    10  |    12 |
| 3  |    14  |    16 |
| 4  |    25  |    30 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Some more words of explanations:

- As you see I used user-defined variables to *number* lines (required to match them by pair easily)
- I used the `JOIN (SELECT @j := 0)` trick to initialize those variables without requiring a separate `SET ...` statement
- I simplified the problem here by using range of integers in order to keep the answer *understandable* by reducing the "noise". You will have to adapt it for `DATETIME`.
- I uses "pure SQL" to find the answer as it was required originally, but as there is some matching based on the "row numbers", it would have probably been most efficient to solve that part of the problem at application level ;)

---

Here is *only for reference* my original answer. It produces the *complement* of the right query by issuing [hired,fired] intervals.

Say you have an interval [@start @end)

```
SELECT DISTINCT GREATEST(@start, hired), LEAST(@end, fired)
 FROM hirefire
 WHERE @start < fired AND @end >= hired;
```

I'm not quite sure of the inequality/strict inequality thing, but that's the spirit.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a841d0/7 for an example. It uses plain integers to define ranges, but you will be able to adapt that to `DATETIME` without too much efforts, I think.

Comment: It is not what I need. I need intervals

Comment: @porton I probably didn't understand ... but as of myself, the range between `LEAST(...)` and `GREATEST(...)` *is* an interval. As it is, the query return all non-empty intersection of each interval with [ @start, @end). As this is apparently more complex, could you provide your own sqlfiddle as an (simplified) example + the *expected* output.

Comment: I need interval with values from two *different* (adjacent) rows of the table. This is the complex part. See the question

Comment: Sylvain: The question is to retrieve all the intervals where the person is NOT working (fire intervals). Your query retrieves all the intervals where the person IS working (hire intervals).

Comment: @SteveKass Thank you Steve: that was exactly the key point I was missing. By the same way, making the question much more interesting !

Comment: @porton For the "beauty of the thing", I've updated my answer to something more in the spirit of what you asked first.

Comment: Nice job, Sylvain. MySQL is out of my expertise, so once I verified that LAG() and LEAD() - which make problems like this relatively simple - I didn't think I had more to contribute.